# MySQL Use where for count of a group

Tags: mysql

I've wrote this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(ProductID) AS ProNumber, userID
FROM orderLog WHERE time >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY userID ORDER BY ProNumber DESC
```

And i want to do that:

```
SELECT COUNT(ProductID) AS ProNumber, userID
FROM orderLog WHERE time >= CURDATE() AND ProNumber > 1000
GROUP BY userID ORDER BY ProNumber DESC
```

But it doesn't work.
why? how can i fix this query?

Comment: Can  you share your tables structure ?

Comment: HAVING COUNT(ProductID) > 1000 is antoher option

Comment: You should read up on mysql order of execution. - the where clause is executed before the select ie. prodnumber is not available to the where clause, you should use the having cllause in group by,

Answer (score 2):

Because your alias `ProNumber` is not yet known by MySQL when the WHERE clause is executed. You should not use a column alias in the WHERE clause

If you want to keep only the the records with COUNT(*) > 1000, you should use the HAVING clause that filters the records after a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT COUNT(ProductID) AS ProNumber, userID
FROM orderLog 
WHERE time >= CURDATE() 
GROUP BY userID 
HAVING COUNT(ProductID) > 1000
ORDER BY ProNumber DESC
```

If that's not what you want, add explanations because it is not clear

Answer (score 0):

let's try this :-)

```
SELECT COUNT(ProductID) AS ProNumber, userID
FROM orderLog WHERE time >= CURDATE() AND ProductID> 1000
GROUP BY userID ORDER BY ProductID DESC
```

Comment: This will count only those products with an ID > 1000. The OP wants users with more than 1000 products.